# Excel doesn't open IP-Hyperlinks in browser

Tags: excel, vba

So down below is the code I'm using to create a hyperlink with an IP address. My Problem is that when I click on the link the standard-browser won't open. The only thing I get is this:

[image]

Translating the image it says:

> *The Server "192.168.0.10" needs your Username and Password. The Server is from "Test".*

The rest of the text is not necessary. After entering the username and password it immediately enters "No Respons". So for me it looks like that excel itself wants to open the IP-link.

Is there a way to add something to the code so it uses for example: Internet Explorer?

```
With Worksheets(1)
.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(Application.Max(2, Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row + 1), 5), _
Address:="http://" & IP_Adresse, _
TextToDisplay:=IP_Adresse
End With
```